# what is lift in these terms?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am unable to comprehend this  "Each vector $w(t)$ lifts to the vector $q(t)$"
is it trying to say that the smooth curve $y(t)$ in $\Bbb R^d $ and there is a tangent  $w(t)$ in $\Bbb R^d $   at $y(t)$ , then this vector lifts to the vector $q(t)$ in $\Sigma $ . am i correct or it means something different .

where $I$ is the identity matrix,$J$ is the jacobian,$\Sigma $ is an imbedding in $\Bbb R^d$ . 
$\Sigma= \{y/F(y) :y \in \Bbb{R^d}\}$
A curve $y(t)$ in $\Bbb{R^d}$ lifts to a curve $x(t)=(y/F(y) )$ in $\Sigma $ 
and the tangent vector $v(t)=\dot {y}(t)$ in $\Bbb{R^d}$ lifts to the tangent vector $$u(t)=(I,J(y(t))^Tv(t)$$ to $\Sigma $ at $x(t)$
$J=\frac{\partial F()}{\partial y}$
[image: lcf]
 [image: msl]

Comment: There are lots of undefined terms : what are $\Sigma$, $I$, $J$, $F$ ?

Comment: edited @CaptainLama

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? $J$ is the Jacobian of what? the embedding $\Sigma$? And $\Sigma$ is an embedding of what? Just some submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^d$? Of what dimension?

Comment: edited the @Nick